# MVC HTML Helper DropDownListFor not submitting the selected value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

jQuery form serialize is not submitting the value of the drop down list to the controller. The control is getting the ID and the Name from the way i have it in the .cshtml file.

HTML-code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "productForm" })) 
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.OnlineProduct.Class_Id, HelperMethods.LoadProductClass(Model.BrandType), new { @class = "col-sm-2", @style = "width:266px;font-family:monospace;height:30px;float:left" })
}
```

jQuery

```
$.post('/Product/ReviseProduct', $('#productForm').serialize() + '&brandId=' + $('#BrandId').val() + '&brandType=' + $('#BrandType').val())
```

Controller-code

```
public ActionResult ReviseProduct(ProductViewModel vModel, int brandId, byte brandType)
```

ViewModel-code

```
public class ProductViewModel { public Online_Product OnlineProduct { get; set; } }
```

ViewPage-Source

```
<select class="col-sm-2" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Class_Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Class_Id field is required." id="OnlineProduct_Class_Id" name="OnlineProduct.Class_Id" style="width:266px;font-family:monospace;height:30px;float:left">
<option value="">Choose ...</option>
<option value="23">Aloe</option>
<option value="4">Sparkling</option>
<option selected="selected" value="3">White</option>
<option value="17">Wine Cooler</option>
</select>
```

Please help why does the controller not getting the value for this dropdown.

Comment: please show us your controller signature

Comment: updated the post with controller signature. The OnlineProduct object is in the view model. Other form fields are being submitted correctly.

Comment: There's not really enough here to do more than guess. What does your view model look like? How is the form created? Those are relevant.

Comment: What is `#productForm` ?

Comment: #productForm is the html form in .cshtml like this ```@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "productForm" })) and public class ProductViewModel { public Online_Product OnlineProduct { get; set; } }

Comment: Comments are not built for large chunks of code - edit that into your question. We need to see where `@Html.DropDownListFor(...)` is added, relative to your form.

Comment: I edited the question to add more details, sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not really seeing anything in your question that looks like an obvious error. If you open your browser's developer tools, and switch to the Network tab, do you see any data being sent with the AJAX request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a hidden field in the form to get the value
 @Html.HiddenFor(n => n.OnlineProduct.Class_Id)
Now the viewmodel is receiving the selected value on the object

Answer (score 0):

What if you try switching `$('#productForm').serialize()` to

`'vModel={"OnlineProduct":{"Class_Id":' + $('#productForm select').val() + '}}'`

I believe your `$('#productForm').serialize()` will return a string such as `'OnlineProduct.Class_Id=3'` (I tested) and your controller can't recognize that value to deserialize it into your `ProductViewModel` object.

Comment: I have 7 other inputs that i am sending while submitting this form. It is mix of textbox, checkbox and this one dropdown.